# Variable inside quotes

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to pass a variable into an Ansible playbook.

```
ansible-playbook script.yml --extra-vars "status=false"
```

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
  

- name: Enable fact
    set_fact:
      facts: '{{ facts | combine({ "configured_status": "{{status}}" })}}'
    vars:
      facts: '{{ facts_raw.content|b64decode }}'

  - debug:
      var: facts
```

However, The debug output is:

```
 "configured_status": "{{status}}"
```

Instead of:

```
"configured_status": "false"
```

Anyone knows what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you want `"false"` (a string) or `false` (a boolean)?

Comment: It supposed to be a string ("false")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```yaml
facts: '{{ facts | combine({ "configured_status": status })}}'
```

Why are you decoding facts? If you used slurp then

```yaml
  - name: Enable fact
    set_fact:
      facts: "{{ facts_raw.content|b64decode|from_json|default([])| combine({ 'configured_status': status }) }}"

  - debug:
      var: facts
```

Comment: Actually this also works because the `key=value` form of `extra-vars` is always assumed string by Ansible.

Comment: @anatogx Works great.  I'm indeed using slurp

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you are passing your variables to `extra-vars` this can be as simple as

```yaml
facts: '{{ facts | combine({ "configured_status": status }) }}'
```

This is actually pointed in the documentation:

> Values passed in using the `key=value` syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line*</sup>

So you don't even have to protect you from Ansible treating it as a boolean, as in the playbook below.

---

Now, would you pass it as a real boolean:

```sh
ansible-playbook script.yml --extra-vars '{ "status": false }'
```

Then, nesting Jinja delimiters would never lead you to any good.

Here, what you want to use is the contatenation operator of Jinja [`~`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators), so you can concatenate a string and the variable that `status` holds.

Given the playbook, *play.yml*:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: '{{ facts | combine({ "configured_status": "" ~ status ~ "" })}}'
      vars:
        facts: 
          foo: bar
```

Run with the command

```sh
ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars "status=false"
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "configured_status": "false",
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```